# converting column names to integer with read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matrix

I have constructed a matrix with integer values for columns and index. The matrix is acutally hierachical for each month. My problem is that the indexing and selecting of data does not work anymore as before when I write the data to csv and then load as pandas dataframe.

Selecting data before writing and reading data to file:

```
matrix.ix[1][4][3]
```

would for example give `123`

In words select, month January and get me the (travel) flow from origin 4 to destination 3.

After writing and reading the data to csv and back into pandas, the original referencing fails but if I convert the column indexing to string it works:

```
matrix.ix[1]['4'][3]
```

... the column names have automatically been tranformed from integer into string. But I would prefer the original indexing.
Any suggestions?

My current quick fix for handling the data after loading from csv is:

```
# Writing df to file
mulitindex_df_Travel_monthly.to_csv(
    r'result/Final_monthly_FlightData_countrylevel_v4.csv')

# Loading df from csv
test_matrix = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_inputdata + '/Final_monthly_FlightData_countrylevel_v4.csv',
    index_col=[0, 1])

test_matrix.rename(columns=int, inplace=True)  # Thx, @ayhan
```

CSV FILE:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u2opzh65zwcn81/travel_matrix_SO.csv?dl=0

[image: example df]

Comment: Can you share a few lines of the CSV and how you read it?

Comment: I added the code I am using to save the data and load it back into pandas. I am only specifiying the index_col. But there is at least a minor issue as well. Once loaded its adds me a empty row with name "Unnamed: 1"

Comment: Add the other arguments: `header=None, skiprows=1`

Comment: @ Parfait, did you test this one the dataset I provided in your environment? It does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```py
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)
```

or

```py
df.columns = df.columns.map(int)
```

Related: [what is difference between .map(str) and .astype(str) in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782934/what-is-difference-between-mapstr-and-astypestr-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this:

```
df = df.rename(columns={str(c): c for c in columns})
```

where df is pandas dataframe and columns are column to change

Comment: If you know `columns`, then you can use `pd.read_csv(..., names=columns)`.

Comment: @bers This code only changes a subset, not necessarily all columns

Comment: I suspect you are talking about your code, in which case you are correct. The OP's solution posted before your answer is `test_matrix.rename(columns=int, inplace=True)`, so I suspect we are talking about renaming *all* columns.